# Issue centering placeholder inside a textfield

Tags: swift, uitextfield

Essentially I have the following code for a textfield to display a button on the right side when a no text is present, I also have some placeholder text text for the textfield that is displaying off center. Is there anyway to have the place holder text stay centered when there is a button in rightViewMode?

```
let centeredParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    centeredParagraphStyle.alignment = .center
    let attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Scan", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: centeredParagraphStyle])
serialTF.attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder
let wSize = serialTF.frame.size.height - 2
let scanSerialButton = UIButton( type: .custom )
scanSerialButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "barcodeScan"), for: .normal )
scanSerialButton.addTarget( self, action: #selector(scanSerial), for: .touchUpInside )
scanSerialButton.frame = CGRect( x: wSize, y: 0, width: wSize, height: wSize )
let wV = UIView()
wV.frame = CGRect( x:0, y:0, width: wSize * 2, height: wSize )
wV.addSubview(scanSerialButton)
serialTF.rightView = wV;
serialTF.rightViewMode = .unlessEditing;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `UITextField` and it will provide a chance to customize the placeholder frame like this.

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        // return what you want from here
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I specifically center the placeholder text within the subclass? I appreciate the help

Comment: Check the total width of textField - a) try providing this full width to placeholder. OR b) calculate what's the width required for your placeholder text, subtract this from total width, based on this adjust x & width of the placeholder rect you will return from above method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't embed the button in a view assign button directly to the rightView

```
txtField.rightView = scanSerialButton
```